# Socket.io namespaces and room : cannot receive an event on a particular url with token

Tags: node.js, socket.io, namespaces

Currently, I need to code a nodejs server to provide the real-time position to all users who have the token. So I use socket.io and express. 
For the moment I only send messages when a button is pressed before I start sending positions in JSON format.

The client sends an event with a message and the server retrieves it before sending a new message to clients with the same token as the first client.

My problem is the following: I can send a message from the client but the server does not retrieve the corresponding event and therefore cannot send its response.
Do you have any explanation?

Server :

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = 8080;
var tokenArray = [];


app.get('/suivi/:token', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/src/suiveur.html");
});

app.get("/createChannel/:token", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.token);
    var newNamespace = io.of("/" + req.params.token);
    tokenArray.push(newNamespace);

    newNamespace.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room.substring(1, room.length));
      });
    });

    newNamespace.on('afficheTest', function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
      newNamespace.to("/" + req.params.token).emit('afficheTest', "Salut les amis");
    });

    res.send("OK");
});

//Création d'une route dynamique pour servir le css
app.get("/css/:nomFichierCss", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/css/" + req.params.nomFichierCss);
});

//Création d'une route dynamique pour servir les scripts
app.get("/script/:nomScript", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/script/" + req.params.nomScript);
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Client's side script :

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  initMap();

  $(function() {
    localStorage.debug = '*';
    //On récupère le token
    var room = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/"), window.location.href.length);
    //On se connecte au bon salon
    var socket = io.connect(room);
    //On détecte un évènement indiquant que la personne a bougé
    socket.on("newPositionAppears", (tableau) => {
        if(tableau != null) {
            tableau.forEach((polyLine) => {
                //On part du principe qu'il s'agit d'un tableau de polyLine
                map.entities.push(polyLine);
            })
        }
    });

$('#affichons').on("click", function() {
    alert("Click");
    socket.emit("afficheTest", "Salut bb");
});

    socket.on("afficheTest",  function(msg) {
        console.log("Affiche Test : ");
        alert(msg)
    });
    socket.on("connect", function() {
        socket.emit("room", room);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: How you start your server. Means by pm2 or just node? If you are using pm2 and receiving event some times then its problem with a multi-cluster mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing 2 socket.io concepts : namespaces and rooms.

Namespaces are a concept that is shared between the client and the server: the client can decide to connect to a namespace and it works only if the namespace has been created before on the server.

On the other hand, rooms is a concept that only exists server-side: the client can perform some action and the server places the socket in a room.

In a typical scenario, namespaces are static (ex: "/admin", "/notifications", etc.) and created during the server startup while rooms are dynamic and created on demand (like chatrooms).

In your case, it could mean the following:

1. Let the client emit a socket.io message on the default namespace ("/", the one that already exists by default). The message could be `join` and the payload `{ "token": <the token> }`
2. Then the server should place the socket in the corresponding room. The room could be named something like `locations-${token}`.
3. From this point, you can send messages to all the sockets in the room with `io.to('locations-1234567890').emit('new_location', { foo: 'bar' })`